# app for Android TV rejected from Google Play with the reason: Skip button on the Now Playing card cannot be selected with the D-pad

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an app published on Google Play for 3 years. The app is also compatible with Android TV.
Suddenly my app is rejected for Android TV.
The reason I'm getting from Google is that the "Skip" button on the "Now Playing" card cannot be selected with the D-pad.
As I see on an Android TV device, also on emulators, the Now Playing card contains only two buttons, OPEN and STOP, they work fine in my app. Also, some other apps for Android TV, for example Spotify, display the exact style of the Now Playing card.
I filed a complaint on Google Play but have not received any further information on this issue.
Am I missing something on the Now Playing card? Anyone facing the same issue? What is finally the "Skip" button in the Now Playing card?
[Now Playing card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FFb9.png)

I did all the tests to confirm that my app has full functionality using a d-pad.
I've compared other "Now Playing" cards of similar Apps on Google Play.